# Assign a list of numbers to a set of range

Tags: sql, oracle

Supposed I have 3 different ZIP

```
91000
91200
91500
```

and I have 3 different range

```
91000 - 91199
91200 - 91499
91500 - 95000
95001 - 96000
```

How do I go about writing a query that helps me assign the ZIP code to the according range? The issue is that my ZIP code comes from table A, I need to look up the zip in table B, but table B only houses the range, not the actual ZIP. So I cannot do a join between table A and B.

I tried the following but it didn't work. Thanks a bunch!

```
select * from data.zip a
where (select zip_cd from data.mkt_zip b
where zip_cd in ('91000','91200','91500')) between from_zip_cd and to_zip_cd
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific what you're trying to accomplish?  Are you just looking for `where '95209' between from_zip_cd and to_zip_cd`?

Comment: yes. I am just trying to see if 95209 falls between from and to zip code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Your syntax is wrong.

Take a look at the SQL BETWEEN operator [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `join` these two tables using proper join condition:

```
select a.zip_cd, b.from_zip_cd, b.to_zip_cd
  from zip a
  join mkt_zip b on a.zip_cd between b.from_zip_cd and b.to_zip_cd
```

Output:

```
ZIP_CD FROM_ZIP_CD  TO_ZIP_CD
------ ----------- ----------
91000        91000      91199 
91200        91200      91499 
91500        91500      95000
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69873/1)

---

Of course you can use additional filters in `where` clause or in condition for `join`:

```
select a.zip_cd, b.from_zip_cd, b.to_zip_cd
  from zip a
  join mkt_zip b on a.zip_cd between b.from_zip_cd and b.to_zip_cd
  where a.zip_cd in ('91000', '91500')


select a.zip_cd, b.from_zip_cd, b.to_zip_cd
  from zip a
  join mkt_zip b on a.zip_cd between b.from_zip_cd and b.to_zip_cd
                and a.zip_cd in ('91000', '91500')
```